# Pre-calculating the normals, ways to do it? C++, OpenGL 4

Tags: c++, opengl, optimization, normals

Given that I need to perform

```
Normal = mat3(transpose(inverse(model))) * normal;
```

this per vertex normal to efficiently render a model. My current scenario, is that I am importing a model via assimp, and loading it into a vertex and element buffer object. Having now built the VAO how do I update the normals before I bind the model to be rendered.

Do I have to use glBufferSubData or glMapBuffer? Is there a simpler solution where I can isolate the model's normals from the rest of the model's VAO within another VAO and use both attribute objects to render the model? Could I maybe create a texture with the pre-calculated normals and pass that?

Am not sure what to do here, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure you truly understand what a VAO is. It's not something you can "build," insofar as you don't store data in pointers. The two API commands you listed are for Buffer Objects. Array Objects are just state containers - they hold pointers to buffer objects.

Comment: Just calculate the transpose-inverse in your C++ code, and pass it as a second uniform matrix into the shader. Depending on what transformations you use, it's mostly not even needed. As long as you only have rotations, uniform scaling, and translations, you can apply the model matrix without the translation part to transform the normals.